# How to fix linting error with React's setState()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, lint, tslint

I am trying to figure out an error I get when linting my React TypeScript project. The problem is within a component when setting the state:

```
this.setState({dialogStatus: DialogNoConfigurationFileStatus.Create});
```

The error I get when linting:

```
Property 'creationStep' is missing in type '{ dialogStatus: DialogNoConfigurationFileStatus.Create; }'.
Error at src/dialogs/dialog-no-configuration-file.tsx:137:23: Argument of type '{ creationStep: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DialogNoConfigurationFileState'.
```

The structure of the component:

```
export interface DialogNoConfigurationFileState {
    dialogStatus: DialogNoConfigurationFileStatus;
    creationStep: number;
}

export class DialogNoConfigurationFile extends React.Component<DialogNoConfigurationFileProps, DialogNoConfigurationFileState> {
    public constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dialogStatus: DialogNoConfigurationFileStatus.Enter,
            creationStep: 0
        };
    }

    ...

}
```

My assumption is that I get the linting error, because both params within the interace DialogNoConfigurationFileState are obligatory. When setting them both to optional the error is gone:

```
export interface DialogNoConfigurationFileState {
    dialogStatus?: DialogNoConfigurationFileStatus;
    creationStep?: number;
}
```

I would like to leave them obligatory though. The reason for that is, because I want to force the creation of the state within the constructor. This way I am sure the state is set when accessing `this.state.creationStep` from within the component. If I set the state param to optional, I have to check first if the state and the state's params are assigned. A step I would like to avoid.

What is the best thing to be done here? Am I unconsciously creating bad code here? Even though linting fails, the code still runs well, but the people behind TSLint must have had a thought behind this error.

Could someone please elaborate?

**EDIT 1:**

This the enum DialogNoConfigurationFileStatus:

```
export enum DialogNoConfigurationFileStatus {
    Enter,
    Create,
}
```

Comment: assuming `DialogNoConfigurationFileStatus` is an Enum, can you add it to your post?

Comment: @SandraWillford Added the enum to the post.

Comment: I dropped this into a local project and didn't get any linting errors. you may want to make sure you typescript & tslint packages are up to date.

Comment: @SandraWillford is right, old TypeScript defs are the problem here. See my answer for a workaround in case you can't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the [latest TypeScript definitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react) for React (16.8.5 at time of writing) then this shouldn't be an issue any more - older definitions don't allow 'partial' updates of state but this was fixed at some point.

If it's not possible to update, and you really want to keep the fields obligatory, you can use casting as a workaround to make the type error go away

```
this.setState({
  dialogStatus: DialogNoConfigurationFileStatus.Create
} as DialogNoConfigurationFileState);
```

This essentially tells TypeScript:

> Trust me, this is a valid `DialogNoConfigurationFileState`, I know what I'm doing.